# inserting html into yahoo's YUI rich text editor

Tags: dom, yui, yahoo, javascript

I am trying to insert HTML into the YUI rich text editor. The code works if I use simple HTML snippets, but if I use something more complicated (e.g. try to embed an object), then it fails.

**Edit**

Fails - only for FF browser

For example - this works:

```
var html = '<div><b><u>Hello world!</u></b></div>';
myEditor.execCommand('inserthtml', html);
```

**But this dosen't work:**

```
var html = '<div><object width="640" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/OVXIh4q-OmM?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/OVXIh4q-OmM?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385"></embed></object></div>';

myEditor.execCommand('inserthtml', html);
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Some tags get cleaned up, according the editor object's settings.

[YUI Rich Editor + invalidHTML + style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303999/yui-rich-editor-invalidhtml-style) explains the "invalidHTML" concept and has some example code to explain.